# 「ゼロからのOS自作入門」の内容について：割り込みの記述(７章)をg++でコンパイル可能か

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

「ゼロからのOS自作入門」にg++での挑戦を試みています。
環境はUbuntu20.04.02、g++9.3.0です。

現在、USBからのマウス操作を、ポーリングによる検知から割り込みによる検知に変えるという作業の途中です。（購読されている方は、7章です）ここで割り込みハンドラの記述のため、以下のような関数を作成することになりました。

```
//main.cpp
__attribute__((interrupt))
void IntHandlerXHCI(InterruptFrame* frame) {
  main_queue->Push(Message{Message::kInterruptXHCI});
  NotifyEndOfInterrupt();
}
```

これをコンパイルすると、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
main.cpp:86:42: sorry, unimplemeted: SSE instructions aren't allowed in an interrupt service routine
```

調べたところ、どうやら割り込みを記述する際には汎用レジスタのみを利用するようにコンパイラに指示する必要があるため、オプションで-mgeneral-regs-onlyを付加しなければならないらしいと知り、今度はこれを付加してコンパイルを試みたところ、次のようなエラーが出ました。

```
In file included from /home/(私の名前)/osbook/devenv/x86_64-elf/include/c++/v1/numeric:143,
                 from main.cpp:6:
/home/(私の名前)/osbook/devenv/x86_64-elf/include/c++/v1/limits: In static member function ‘static constexpr std::__1::__libcpp_numeric_limits<float, true>::type std::__1::__libcpp_numeric_limits<float, true>::min()’:
/home/(私の名前)/osbook/devenv/x86_64-elf/include/c++/v1/limits:313:77: error: SSE register return with SSE disabled
  313 |     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR type min() _NOEXCEPT {return __FLT_MIN__;}
      |                                                                             ^
/home/(私の名前)/osbook/devenv/x86_64-elf/include/c++/v1/limits: In static member function ‘static constexpr std::__1::__libcpp_numeric_limits<long double, true>::type std::__1::__libcpp_numeric_limits<long double, true>::min()’:
/home/(私の名前)/osbook/devenv/x86_64-elf/include/c++/v1/limits:405:77: error: x87 register return with x87 disabled
  405 |     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY static _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR type min() _NOEXCEPT {return __LDBL_MIN__;}
      |
```

main.cppではnumericをインクルードしているため、それが原因であろうということは察しが付きましたが、試しにのインクルードを外してみたところ、その他のファイルで多数使用されているfunctional、array、optionalなども同様のエラーの発生源となっていました。

しかし、著者が想定環境としているclang(及びclang++)ではコンパイルが成功し、何もエラーが出ません。
そこでお聞きしたいのが、

1. 結局、著者のソースコードに概ね従う限り、g++でコンパイルを行うことは不可能なのでしょうか？それとも、何か付加すべきオプションがあるのでしょうか？
2. `-mgeneral-regs-only` を付加するべきであるという私の理解は正しいのでしょうか？著者の用意したMakefileの設定やビルド用の環境変数の設定には、これに対応すると思しきオプションは見当たりません。clangではこのようなオプションを付加しなくても、割り込み `__attribute__((interrupt))` を記述すれば、SSEレジスタの使用が抑制されるということなのでしょうか？

ご存知の方いらっしゃれば、ご教授願いたく存じます。

Comment: タイトルと質問事項が一致していないように思えます。タイトルのエラーを解消したいのでしょうか。それとも書籍の内容(コードを含む)について質問をしたいのでしょうか。本文を尊重すると、「『ゼロからのOS自作入門』の学習にg++を使用できますか？」のようなタイトルがふさわしいかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問したかったことは、表題のエラーを解決したいということが主であるつもりでした。つまり質問の主旨は、「作者のソースコードをコンパイルできるか」というよりも、「本文中で挙げさせていただいたヘッダをインクルードした上で割り込みハンドラを記述したソースコードは、g++でコンパイル可能か、可能ならばどのような方法があるか」ということでした。そしてそれに付随して、現在エラーが起こっている原因を知りたく、２．の質問を付加しました。ただ、確かに表題と本文の内容にはミスマッチがあると見るのは自然かとも思うので、表題の方で、「ゼロからのOS自作入門」についての質問であると明記しようと思います。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. 結局、著者のソースコードに概ね従う限り、g++でコンパイルを行うことは不可能なのでしょうか？それとも、何か付加すべきオプションがあるのでしょうか？

ソースコードが提示されない状態だと、可能とも不可能とも言えないかと思います。

筆者がclangを前提にしていて単に「g++が考慮外」なのであれば、「動けばラッキー」ぐらいです。

---

コンパイルエラーになっている箇所は、ビルドオプションにもよるでしょうが下記のようなコードになるかと思います。

```cpp
static constexpr float min() noexcept {return __FLT_MIN__;}
```

g++ 10.1.0までは、未使用の浮動小数点数を使用するconstexpr関数でも`-mgeneral-regs-only`が指定されているとエラーになるようです。
[g++ 11.1.0ではエラーにならない](https://wandbox.org/permlink/M8genMBwfTwsG90r)ので、g++ 11.1.0以降を使用すれば状況が改善されるかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ソースコードは自分が思う必要箇所を列挙するととんでもない量の本文になってしまうので、このような形になってしまいました。申し訳ございません。
g++のバージョンによる結果の違いは全く思いつきませんでした。早速試してみようと思います。

Comment: しばらく放ったらかしで申し訳ございません。g++-11にアップデートしたところ、無事コンパイルすることができました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

この辺の話は Application Binary Interface (ABI) 仕様の理解（ならびに著者と読者間での合意）がないと説明できないし、オイラはその本もっていませんのでなんともいえないのですが

まず ABI の解説から
関数の引数や返却値ってのは限りなく抽象的なものであるのに対し
CPU のレジスタやスタックってのは物理的なものであって、
その両者をどう結び付けるとか、関数の呼び出し前後でレジスタやスタックがどう変化する/させるとか、その他の諸々、関数を呼ぶ側・呼ばれる側で守るべき規則の仕様を ABI といいます。
[x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) とか [The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/) とか
これを守れば１つのプログラムの中に A 社のコンパイラと B 社のコンパイラを混在して使うことができたりして楽ができることになります。

独自 OS を作るってことは CPU メーカやコンパイラメーカの提案してきた ABI ではなく、独自のオレオレ ABI を採用することも可能です。オレオレ ABI を採用する以上は、それに適合するコンパイラやリンカーやデバッガを自作しなければならないですが。

なのであなたの・その本の著者が作ろうとしているオレオレ OS が「割り込みハンドラで SSE レジスタを使ってよい」という規則を採用するなら、今使っている [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) の規則と喧嘩しているので [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) のほうにパッチを当てて [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) 側の規則変更を行う必要があります。逆にオレオレ OS を [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) の仕様に合わせて規則選定するなら「割り込みハンドラで SSE レジスタを使っちゃならない」わけです。

全く同様のことが [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) でも言えます。よって

- [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) / [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) のデフォルト ABI 規則をオレオレ OS で採用する
  なら [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) / [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) に特別なオプションを指定しなくてよい
- [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) / [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) のデフォルト ABI 規則をオレオレ OS で採用しない
  なら [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) / [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) の動作をオレオレ OS の規則にあうように変更するオプションを指定する必要がある

手元にある [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) x86_64 用の [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc)-10.2.0 と [clang](/questions/tagged/clang)-8.0.1 では `__attribute__((interrupt))` を使ったとき生成される機械語が異なります（＝採用している ABI が異なる）。そのため、コンパイラを変更するとかコンパイルオプションを変更するとは即ち ABI を変更するということになります。逆にいえば、採用した ABI に合致するような機械語を生成するコンパイルオプションを探して指定する必要があるってことです。

x86 でなくて独自 CPU を採用している組み込み系では、コンパイラの ABI 仕様に合わせて OS を設計したりしますので、コンパイラの変更 (ABI が異なる) は OS の仕様の策定しなおしだったりします。

Q1. Q2 とも「オレオレ OS の仕様次第。オレオレ OS で採用することにした ABI に合致するコードを生成させるようにコンパイルオプションを指定するとよい」という回答になるでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。書籍中にもABIについての記述がありましたが、どのようなものかきちんと理解しておりませんでした。この書籍では「System V AMD64 ABIを前提とする」という記述がありましたので、そちらについても調べつつ、適切なオプションを探りたいと思います。

Comment: SysV AMD64 ABI 仕様の詳細は提示 wikipedia から Intel/AMD のページを参照。ここ SO でも AMD ABI で検索するとオイラの記事がヒットしたり・・・分量が膨大なので原文を読むのが困難なら有志によるオレオレ翻訳解説記事など探してみると吉。 x64 ABI の詳細を知ってみるとアセンブラ手書きなど絶対したくなくなります。コンパイラありきの仕様なので